# ''Install Prohibited" iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, profiler

I am a registered Apple dev with the certificates, and mobileprofiles that i need.  I have made several apps in xCode that I would like to test on my 3GS, I have registered my 3GS as one of my allowed devices but it still will not install giving the install prohibited error.  The Xcode is set to same profile as my iphone has.  Just dont kmow what to do. well i guess i =ll download sdk 4.1

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: The exact error message is An unknown error message 'InstallProhibited', was received from the device."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your SDK to 4.0.1 to use it with iOS 4.0.1 devices.

Comment: You can also use the current 4.1 golden master SDK, or wait til next week for a release 4.1 SDK.

Comment: Oh...i am downloading the pre release of sdk 4 preview 3, will that work?

Comment: ok i think i will use the gm and then upgrade later... thanks guys

Comment: @DanielsCaleb0 - That's Xcode 4 Developer Preview 3 you're referring to, not the iPhone SDK.  They are different things.  Xcode is Apple's IDE, but you'll need the iPhone SDK to target the iPhone itself.  You want the mainline Xcode (3.2.3, I believe), not the Xcode 4 developer preview.  As hotpaw2 says, you'll need at least the 4.0.1 SDK to target your 4.0.1 device, and you should probably upgrade to the 4.1 gold master while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am trying to download the sdk now, the  slow connection speed here...I know this is probably not s subject to talk about here but i dont wanna upgrade my 3GS cause it is unofficially unlocked..

Comment: Well i Found my problem, my app store was turned off under restrictions and that was prohibiting me from installing apps of any sort.

Answer (score 21):

You will get this exact message if Restrictions are enabled on the device, specifically the restriction on installing Apps.

Comment: Thank You JHos, this is the exact problem, I turned off my restrictions and the problem was fixed.

Comment: This **[link](http://strategybusinesscoding.blogspot.com/2011/08/xcode-unknown-error-message.html)** can help too.

Answer (score 0):

Is the iPhone OS Deployment Target in your Build Settings (either for the project or for the target) set for an OS version higher than the one on your 3GS?

Comment: Nope, the active sdk is set to ios 4, and my 3GS is on iOS 4.0.1, the 3GS is on 4.0.1 and i dont know if the sdk has to bet set to that?

Comment: under the organize window i xcode says that "xcode cannot find software image for this version" maybe i need to upgrade xcode to xcode 4?

Comment: Ok actually the software image message says"xcode cannot find the software image to install this version"