# "Install prohibited" when trying to install ad hoc .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, installation, ipa

I have the following problem - I am trying to install `ad hoc .ipa` file on my iPad 2, model `MC979HC/A with iOS version 6.1.3`. But when I try to install the app via iPhone Configuration Utility or iTunes it says: "`An unknown error message 'Install Prohibited', was received from the device.`"
My app was created by using `Xcode 4.6.1`. I installed the same app on iPad 2 with iOS version 6.0. 
What is the problem, because I can't find any solution on the internet? I guess it can be something with the version of `Xcode` and iOS. I also have to mention that in my iPad 2 General Settings, Restrictions are disabled. But if I enable the restrictions, the option   "INSTALLING APPS"  is set to  OFF  and it is not active, so I can't really change it. How to activate this option?

Comment: See if any of the suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653114/install-prohibited-iphone-sdk) help at all.

If not, can you try disabling, re-enabling, then disabling Retrictions again? If the install is still prohibited, then there may simply be something awry with the OS install. Try a restore of iOS from iTunes and see if this corrects the issue.

Comment: It is because of the Configuration profile. The problem is that I don't know how to back up it before I delete it, because the iPad is not mine.

Comment: Ok. Can you have the owner of the device alter the restriction or allow you to reset it since it needs to be used to test AdHoc builds?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already installed with other app in your iphone with same Provisioning profile. Please uninstall the app with same provisioning profile which you installed previously and install again a clean build.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem. There was a Configuration Profile on the iPad which had some restrictions by default. I had to delete the profile and then I was able to install apps again. Anyway, thanks for your advices!